# Python Pandas: How to use dictionary on a column which contains a list of keys to create another column of a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns is a list of keys. How do I create another column which has values corresponding to those keys?

Below is the minimal example of the declared dataframe and dictionary

```
ex = pd.DataFrame( {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [[1,2,3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3]]  }) 
ex.head()

    a    b
0   1   [1, 2, 3]
1   2   [3, 2, 1]
2   3   [2, 1, 3]

din = {1: 'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}
```

How do I create another column which uses the dictionary to map each value from each list in column b?

For example, I want to make something like this:

```
    a    b           c
0   1   [1, 2, 3] [A, B, C] 
1   2   [3, 2, 1] [C, B, A] 
2   3   [2, 1, 3] [B, A, C]
```

Usually, to do something like this where the column is not a list, the map function is used like below

```
ex['c'] = ex['b'].map(din)
```

However, since column b is a list and not a key itself, I get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-d5b753372a81> in <module>()
----> 1 ex['c'] = ex['b'].map(din)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   2348         if isinstance(arg, Series):
   2349             # arg is a Series
-> 2350             indexer = arg.index.get_indexer(values)
   2351             new_values = algorithms.take_1d(arg._values, indexer)
   2352         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2682             target = target.astype(object)
   2683             return this.get_indexer(target, method=method, limit=limit,
-> 2684                                     tolerance=tolerance)
   2685 
   2686         if not self.is_unique:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2700                                  'backfill or nearest reindexing')
   2701 
-> 2702             indexer = self._engine.get_indexer(target._values)
   2703 
   2704         return _ensure_platform_int(indexer)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.lookup()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More pandasic way:

```
ex['c']=ex['b'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).map(din).tolist())
print(ex)
```

Output:

```
   a          b          c
0  1  [1, 2, 3]  [A, B, C]
1  2  [3, 2, 1]  [C, B, A]
2  3  [2, 1, 3]  [B, A, C]
```

Your code doesn't work because you're assigning it to the whole column at once, not each value, so you can use `apply` for it

Or:

```
ex['c']=list(map(lambda i: list(map(din.get,i)),ex['b']))
```

Or as @jezrael mentioned:

```
ex['c']=list(map(lambda i: [din.get(a) for a in i],ex['b']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since each value in column is a list, you cannot use `map` directly.
You need to map each value in a list like this:

```
ex['c']=ex['b'].apply(lambda x: [din.get(v) for v in x])

    a   b           c
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   [A, B, C]
1   2   [3, 2, 1]   [C, B, A]
2   3   [2, 1, 3]   [B, A, C]
```

Or as per suggestion by [`Zero`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137255/zero):

```
ex['c'] = ex['b'].apply(lambda L: list(map(din.get, L)))
```

Or as per suggestion by [`jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael):

```
ex['c'] = [list(map(din.get, x)) for x in ex['b']]
```

Comment: Also, `ex['b'].apply(lambda L: list(map(din.get, L)))`

Comment: Or `ex['c'] = [list(map(din.get, x)) for x in ex['b']]`